# Python process each dict in a list without for loop

Tags: python

I have a list of dict like:

```
   data=[{"a":11,"s":21},
         {"a":12,"s":22},
         {"a":13,"s":23},
         {"a":14,"s":24}]
```

I need to convert all values of the key `"s"` to sting and now I am using a for loop to achieve this:

```
for i in range(len(data)):
    data[i]["s"] = str(data[i]["s"])
```

This works but is there any elegant way to process this in one expression?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using for loops is perfectly pythonic and elegant, the only *issue* with your code is that is using [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) to iterate over the elements of a list, do this instead:

```
data = [{"a": 11, "s": 21},
        {"a": 12, "s": 22},
        {"a": 13, "s": 23},
        {"a": 14, "s": 24}]

for e in data:
    e['s'] = str(e['s'])

print(data)
```

**Output**

```
[{'a': 11, 's': '21'}, {'a': 12, 's': '22'}, {'a': 13, 's': '23'}, {'a': 14, 's': '24'}]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Could you please explain why `range` is not suitable here...

Comment: @user2894829 it is suitable, just not needed... Because you only use the indices to access the respective list's elements, why not just loop the elements themselves?

Comment: @user2894829 Read this https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop, particularly the section on range

Answer (score 1):

The loop is the elegant way. Put iterate over the `dict` objects themselves, not the list indices.

```
for d in data:
    d['s'] = str(d['s'])
```

Using a list comprehension unnecessarily builds a new list of the given `dict`s.

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly fine to use for loop: 
However, you should use this structure instead:
`for character in data` , in which character will already be the content and there will be no need to call list[x]

It is less wordy compared to your method:
'for x in range of len(list) 
     action to list[x]`